# Netty TCP Client async messages

Tags: java, tcp, netty, tcpclient

I am building a tcp client to receive and sending messages.
I followed the steps on [Netty user guide](http://netty.io/wiki/user-guide-for-4.x.html) and wrote a simple tcp client with a custom handler extending the `ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter`.

In the hander I store the `ChannelHandlerContext`:

```
 @Override
 public void channelActive (ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
   super.channelActive (ctx);
   this.ctx = ctx;
 }
```

Then I have a send method which uses the `ChannelHandlerContext` to send messages:

```
 public void sendMessage (String msg) {
  if (ctx == null) {
    return;
  }
  ChannelFuture cf = ctx.write (Unpooled.copiedBuffer (msg, CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
  ctx.flush ();
}
```

The other option I have found is to use the `Channel` object in your client class

```
 channel.writeAndFlush (msg);
```

I need to call the send method from a different thread.
What is the best way to do it ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I need to call the send method from a different thread, so it needs to work async." It is not necessarily a consequence. Can you detail the expected workflow  ?

Comment: @davidxxx you're right. It does not have to work async. The only thing that I do is calling the send method from diffrent threads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `ChannelHandlerContext` and `Channel` are thread safe, so you can write from any thread without worrying.

If you use `Channel.write()`,  message will have to travel through the complete pipeline. But if you use `ChannelHandlerContext.write()` it will only have to travel through the upstream handlers in the pipeline. Therefore writing to `ChannelHandlerContext` is more efficient.

And also note that most of the time its better to use `writeAndFlush()` instead of `write()`.

Have a look at [this presentation](http://normanmaurer.me/presentations/2014-facebook-eng-netty/slides.html#1.0) for more details.